# Why echo command doesn't list directory contents when read * (asterisk) from CRLF file?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

There're two files:

**file1.txt** - created on Linux

```
root@localhost:~# file file1.txt
file1.txt: ASCII text
root@localhost:~# od -c file1.txt
0000000   *  \n
```

**file2.txt** - created on Windows

```
root@localhost:~# file file2.txt
file1.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
root@localhost:~# od -c file2.txt
0000000   *  \r  \n
```

---

```
root@localhost:~# ls
myFile1  myFile2  myFile3

root@localhost:~# echo `cat file1.txt`
myFile1  myFile2  myFile3
root@localhost:~# echo `cat file2.txt`
*
```

Why CR (carriage return) in the second file causes echo command not to list directory contents but prints asterisk only?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour imo. You get the same result when typing `echo *` and `echo *\\r` (the syntax for the 2nd echo might be distribution dependent. This was tested on OSX)

Comment: Checked on Debian: `echo *\\r` returns `*\r`

Comment: On debian, the syntax may be something like `echo -e *\r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way that `echo *.txt` shows all files ending in `.txt`, `echo *$'\r'` shows all files ending in carriage returns.

Since you don't have any, it shows the pattern verbatim instead

If you create some, either manually or by accidentally running a script with DOS line terminators, they'll show up:

```
$ touch $'foo\r' $'bar\r'

$ echo *$'\r' | hexdump -C
00000000  62 61 72 0d 20 66 6f 6f  0d 0a                    |bar. foo..|
0000000a
```

(Without the `hexdump`, the carriage returns will cause the output to repeatedly overwrite itself, making it look corrupted or like only one file was matched)